# Force Control on a Tether

Tags: control-theory, classical-mechanics

On the ground, I have a winch driven by a synchronous motor to which I can command a torque input $u$. Parameters of this winch, such as friction $d$ and moment of inertia $J$ are well understood and identified.

The motor drives a drum which can spool a tether on or off. The tether is connected to a flying surf-kite. The dynamics of the kite are not well understood at all, but let's assume they are changing relatively slowly and smoothly.

I want to control the force on the tether which goes from the drum to the kite.

The problem is that using a PID controller that takes $(F_{setpoint} - F_{measured})$ as an input calculate $u$ sometimes results in the line going slack, suddenly rendering $F_{measured} = 0$. Of course, the proportional part of the PID controller then kicks in and wants to drive the force back to $F_{setpoint}$, resulting in a huge overshoot.

Is there a body of theory that treats such "unilateral" control action, i.e. that tracking an increasing $F_{setpoint}$ is much easier than tracking a decreasing one, where there is a danger of the process variable suddenly becoming zero?

Comment: Just a stop-gap, but I'm guessing there is a minimum threshold value X of the line-tension you can measure? You might want to use that as a minimum-value (i.e. if the measured value goes below X, you just keep max(X,measured_value), or 0.8*X or something), so that going to "0" is smoother. Also, the overshoot could very well be caused by the integral part, do you have anti-reset windup implemented?

Comment: We have got anti-windup. Currently, we're using a feed-forward term ($u_{FF} = rF_{setpoint}$, where $r$ is the radius of the drum). We're also using gain scheduling, setting the PID gains higher when $F_{setpoint}$ is higher. Maybe always using a minimum $F_{setpoint} > 0$ is a good idea, I'll try that on the machine.